# Cannot find recorded video that I recorded. How can I dig it out?

Tags: camera, data-recovery, video, google-camera

Earlier today I used Google Camera to record four videos. I clearly hit the record and stop buttons both time. When I got home only two of those showed up in my gallery. The two longer ones did not. Is there some directory, temporary folder or hidden files wherefrom I can retrieve these two missing videos?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: What is the memory information of your phone? and What is the duration of those two missing videos shot?

Comment: In my device the videos are saved under `/DCIM/Camera` of default SD card, but check all SD cards.

Comment: @Lucky - both internal and SD. Videos and images are saved internally. The first one was about 2 minutes, the other one was about 5 minutes. The two that saved were less than 30 seconds each.

Comment: @Firelord - No the only mp4 files I had in my /DCIM/Camera were of those two videos that saved correctly.

Comment: I think you dont have enough memory for you to store..thats the reason you cant find those videos..Clean up your memory and try recording a sample video of 5 mins. and see if you can find there. If you can find it then its an insufficient memory issue due to which it dint store it in your memory.

Comment: That's rather strange @Lucky as I have about 7 gigs free on the internal storage. I'll try to make a longer video and see what happens. Thanks!

Comment: A 5 minute 4k video I just recorded did not save. However, a 1080p video of a similar length did. This is quite bizarre.

Answer (score 1):

I know I came probably too late, but since I had the exact same problem today, and this page is the first result that came, so if it can be useful for anybody :

In my case the videos were in the **DCIM/Camera** folder but hidden, filename started with **.pending-** and I've been able to copy them by connecting my phone to a PC and showing hidden files

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Just for clarity since the question mentioned the "Google Camera" app, could you confirm if this answer is for the same app? Otherwise, you might want to [edit] and mention the recording app you used. Thanks!